# Creating mongodb database with ansible playbook

Tags: mongodb

How i can create MongoDB database with Ansible? is it possible?

If not, can i do this with bash script?

I tried to use mongodb_user module for Ansible, but it cant work without existing table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
- name: Create MongoDB root user siteRootAdmin
  mongodb_user:
    login_port: "27017"
    database: "admin"
    name: "{{ mongodb_admin_user }}"
    password: "{{ mongodb_admin_password }}"
    roles: "root"

- name: Create MongoDB administrative user siteUserAdmin
  mongodb_user:
    login_user: "{{ mongodb_admin_user }}"
    login_password: "{{ mongodb_admin_password }}"
    login_port: "27017"
    database: "e-gov"
    name: "{{ mongodb_user }}"
    password: "{{ mongodb_password }}"
    roles:
      - { db: "admin", role: "readWrite" }
      - { db: "{{ mongodb_database }}", role: "readWrite" }

- name: Create MongoDB backup user siteUserBackup
  mongodb_user:
    login_user: "{{ mongodb_admin_user }}"
    login_password: "{{ mongodb_admin_password }}"
    login_port: "27017"
    database: "e-gov"
    name: "{{ mongodb_backup_user }}"
    password: "{{ mongodb_backup_password }}"
    roles:
      - { db: "admin", role: "backup" }
```

I did this, and it works with ansible 2.2.0^

Comment: I have a question? what happen if you apply this playbook again? The module is idempotent? https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/33832

Comment: So, does this actually create the DB?  Or must that already exist?

Answer (score 0):

Ansible shell (or raw) module and using `mongo --eval="db.getSiblingDB('test').createCollection('empty')"` -command creates test -DB and there empty -collection.

Comment: I tried this path. Gets quite hacky quickly once you need to pass ansible variables in connection string.

Answer (score -1):

Although the accepted answer provides a nice example, you can check [this repository](https://github.com/UnderGreen/ansible-role-mongodb/blob/master/tasks/auth_initialization.yml) for a more complete example. It has everything required to MongoDB setup using Ansible:

```
---
- name: Use different mongod.conf for auth initialization
  template:
    src: mongod_init.conf.j2
    dest: /etc/mongod.conf
    owner: root
    group: root
    mode: 0644
  notify:
    - mongodb restart
    - wait when mongodb is started on localhost

- name: Flush all handlers at this point
  meta: flush_handlers

- name: create administrative user "{{ mongodb_user_admin_name }}"
  mongodb_user:
    database: admin
    name: "{{ item.name }}"
    password: "{{ item.password }}"
    update_password: "{{ mongodb_user_update_password }}"
    roles: "{{ item.roles }}"
    login_host: "{{ mongodb_net_bindip.split(',') | map('replace', '0.0.0.0', '127.0.0.1') | list  | first }}"
    login_port: "{{ mongodb_net_port | int }}"
  with_items:
    - {
      name: "{{ mongodb_user_admin_name }}",
      password: "{{ mongodb_user_admin_password }}",
      roles: "userAdminAnyDatabase"
      }
  no_log: true

- name: create administrative user "{{ mongodb_root_admin_name }}"
  mongodb_user:
    database: admin
    name: "{{ item.name }}"
    password: "{{ item.password }}"
    update_password: "{{ mongodb_user_update_password }}"
    roles: "{{ item.roles }}"
    login_host: "{{ mongodb_net_bindip.split(',') | map('replace', '0.0.0.0', '127.0.0.1') | list  | first }}"
    login_port: "{{ mongodb_net_port | int }}"
  with_items:
    - {
      name: "{{ mongodb_root_admin_name }}",
      password: "{{ mongodb_root_admin_password }}",
      roles: "root"
      }
  no_log: true

- name: create backup user "{{ mongodb_root_backup_name }}"
  mongodb_user:
    database: admin
    name: "{{ item.name }}"
    password: "{{ item.password }}"
    update_password: "{{ mongodb_user_update_password }}"
    roles: "{{ item.roles }}"
    login_host: "{{ mongodb_net_bindip.split(',') | map('replace', '0.0.0.0', '127.0.0.1') | list  | first }}"
    login_port: "{{ mongodb_net_port | int }}"
  with_items:
    - {
      name: "{{ mongodb_root_backup_name }}",
      password: "{{ mongodb_root_backup_password }}",
      roles: "backup,clusterMonitor"
      }
  no_log: true

- name: Move back mongod.conf
  template:
    src: mongod.conf.j2
    dest: /etc/mongod.conf
    owner: root
    group: root
    mode: 0644
  notify:
    - mongodb restart
    - wait when mongodb is started

- name: Flush all handlers at this point
  meta: flush_handlers
```

Answer (score -1):

It looks like this:

```
---
- name: Ensure Mongo dbs are present.
  shell: /usr/bin/mongo -u siteRootAdmin -p "{{ SRA_password }}" --eval "db.getSiblingDB('{{ item.dbname }}').createCollection('{{  item.collection }}')"
  with_items: "{{ mongo_databases | default([]) }}"
  no_log: false
  become: yes
```

Comment: it needs formatting